# Installing from such repository can't be done securely

Tags: 18.04, package-management, 19.04

I just switched to Ubuntu 19.04 from Windows. Whenever I try to install anything from the terminal I get such error which says `installing from such repository can't be done securely hence it is disabled`.

[image: Screenshot of my terminal]

```
mohit@mohit-desktop:~$ sudo apt update
[sudo] password for mohit: 
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Ign:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/atom/ubuntu disco InRelease
Hit:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release
Err:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/atom/ubuntu disco Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 64:ff9b::5bbd:5f53 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/atom/ubuntu disco Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
mohit@mohit-desktop:~$
```

Someone told me to do some stuff in the software & updates and asked me to do uncheck some checkboxes and I dont remember it so can anyone tell that again to me please...

Comment: Please don't provide pictures of text. I can't copy/paste from a picture and copy & see specifics of your issue to paste for a clue as your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an issue with one of the PPA repository you added

More than likely they don't support non LTS version of Ubuntu (or don't support 19.04 yet). You can check and see if they have a repository for your Ubuntu version or try setting up the repository again, but I'd advise you to do the following

Use:

```
apt edit-sources
```

And comment out (put # in front of) the repository that gave the error and you should get rid of that error

Comment: Sorry but i am not skilled enough to do so, actually i have just switched to ubuntu so can you please explain me how to comment out it and thanks by the way

Comment: i am getting the following error                      mohit@mohit-desktop:~$ apt edit-sources
E: Could not open lock file /etc/apt/sources.list - open (13: Permission denied)
mohit@mohit-desktop:~$

Comment: @MohitKulkarni do it with sudo then